# Docker Laravel Websockets - Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

Tags: laravel, docker, dockerfile, laravel-websockets

I have a Docker environment running Laravel and I want to get laravel-websockets working.

When I visit here:

```
http://localhost:8000/laravel-websockets
```

I get the following error:

[image: Websockets error]

Dev tools gives me the following:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:6001/app/local?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.3.1&flash=false' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
```

I've got the following docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
    server:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: dockerfiles/nginx.dockerfile
        ports:
            - "8000:80"
            - "6001:6001"
        volumes:
            - ./src:/var/www/html
            - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
        depends_on:
            - app
    app:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: dockerfiles/php.dockerfile
        volumes:
            - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
```

My php.dockerfile looks like so:

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm-alpine

USER root

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY src .

RUN apk --no-cache add libxml2-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install soap
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

RUN echo 'max_execution_time = 120' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-maxexectime.ini;

EXPOSE 6001
```

I'm by no means an expert so I might be missing something obvious.  Any help appreciated.

============

Edit: Additional info

It's set up locally:

```
'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
            'encrypted' => false,
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => 6001,
            'scheme' => 'http'
        ],
    ],
```

And I've run:

```
php artisan websockets:serve
```

Comment: what steps did you take to reach this point? did you start the websockets server? did you config according to localhost?

Comment: Hi, I've updated the original question to add more info - it's set up locally and I've run websockets:serve

Comment: Just a side note: instead of `apk add` and `docker-php-ext-install` what about using https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies, I'm dumb.

```
services:
    server:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: dockerfiles/nginx.dockerfile
        ports:
            - "8000:80"
            - "6001:6001"   <<<<<<<<
```

Port 6001 needs to be exposed on my app container, not on the server:

```
services:
    app:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: dockerfiles/php.dockerfile
        ports:
            - "6001:6001"   <<<<<<<<
```

Comment: Hi, I've got a similar setup and can not make it work, can you show me your nginx dockerfile and config file please, I am hopeless